# ReactJS: Webpack dev server proxy connection refused

Tags: reactjs

I have npm install and npm start an react application.

When the fe is started I receive these errors:

```
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:9060
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:9000
    External: http://192.168.7.12:9000
 ------------------------------------
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:9000/api/account to http://localhost:8765/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:9000/management/info to http://localhost:8765/ [ECONNREFUSED]
```

So I'm checking the

> webpack.dev.js

about my `devServer`:

```
devServer: {
      hot: true,
      static: {
        directory: './target/classes/static/',
      },
      port: 9060,
      proxy: [
        {
          context: [
            '/api',
            '/services',
            '/management',
            '/swagger-resources',
            '/v2/api-docs',
            '/v3/api-docs',
            '/h2-console',
            '/oauth2',
            '/login',
            '/auth',
          ],
          target: `http${options.tls ? 's' : ''}://localhost:8765`,
          secure: false,
          changeOrigin: options.tls,
        },
      ],
      https: options.tls,
      historyApiFallback: true,
```

How can I resolve this problem??

Thank you

Comment: The error message gives the code `ECONNREFUSED` and points to the url - https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors, where it's explained. Maybe that will bring you closer to the solution

Comment: I have tried yet, but it doesn't give me info that i need to resolve :(

Comment: Make sure the server at port 8765 is running. Also, if that server uses name based virtual hosting you need `changeOrigin: true` to update the `host` header on the proxied request.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Are you on windows? Try with another react app from github like [this](https://github.com/jrichardsz/create-react-app-redux) and share us the result

Comment: HEllo, my problem was my localhost: localhost:8765.. it doesn't work!